# How to store user roles in separate table in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.8

I have following doctrine entities in my Symfony2.8 project.

**User**

```
id
email
username
password
```

**Organization**

```
id
name
subdomain
```

**UserOrganization**

```
organization_id
user_id
roles
```

I need to load user roles from **UserOrganization** table, So how can I override Symfony authentication flow to load user roles from "UserOrganization" entity.

**NOTE:**

**xyz.mydomain.com** here xyz is organization.

so while user tries to login from **xyz** subdomain Symfony2 must read roles for the user from xyz organization's record in **UserOrganization** table

Comment: so it's two questions: how to load user_roles from database and how to access called url in controller. could you split your question please? and what did you try so far?

Comment: Have you setup a oneToMany relation between User and UserOrganization? If so then adjust User::getRoles to return the desired information.  Otherwise, plug in your own user provider which will make the queries.

Comment: normally user roles are stored in same table where username and password fields (lets say user) available, but in my case I want to assign different roles for each linked organization of user.

Comment: yes @Cerda, I have oneToMany relation between User and UserOrganization

Answer (score 1):

You should implement your own [Custom UserProvider](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html)

in which you can Inject the `UserOrganization` repository and query that repository on the implemented provider.

Remember that your `UserOrganization` Entity class must implement [UserInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface.html) in order to be used during the security flow.